# How to create a new linux distro

Tags: distro-recommendation

I want to create a new linux distro with customized name,customized wallpaper,customized packages etc.Can i do it keeping ubuntu 14.04 as base and installing packages etc on it.

Also i have successfully created a livecd using ubuntu uck but when it boots it shows ubuntu photos while installing operating system.

I want my customized photos should be displayed while installing my created operating system.

I know its kind of weard but appreciate if someone can help me... : )

Regards

Comment: I want my customized photos should be displayed while installing my created operating system.Can  i do this with ubuntu UCK????